# select top 8 rows from a random selection SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how I can select top 8 rows from following query. I am very new to SQL.

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (
select TEXT, ID, Details 
from tblTEXT 
where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

) X
order by newid()
```

This query is giving me 31 random rows but I want to select top 8.

I am using following but its not working

```
select top 8 
from 
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (
    select TEXT, ID, Details 
    from tblTEXT 
    where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

    ) X
    order by newid()
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with just:

```
SELECT TOP 8 * FROM (
select TEXT, ID, Details 
from tblTEXT 
where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

) X
order by newid()
```

(The other answers are currently incorrect because they don't give a name for the outer subquery, but only an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query will affect result order anyway, so they have other issues when it comes to reliability)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select top 8 * from 
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (
    select TEXT, ID, Details 
    from tblTEXT 
    where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

    ) X
    order by newid()
)Y
```

and of-course, you are selecting top 8 from top 100 rows, you can also select top 8 directly from the inner query by replacing the `top 100` to `top 8` like this

```
SELECT TOP 8 * FROM (
select TEXT, ID, Details 
from tblTEXT 
where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

) X
order by newid()
```

Comment: its giving me error at the ending bracket ). False syntax near ')'

Comment: Yes, you need to name the outer subquery as well as the inner one (currently `X`)

Comment: The optimizer is free to ignore the `ORDER BY` when it's combined with `TOP 100 PERCENT` - it knows that all results are required so it doesn't have to perform any sorting

Comment: The first query does not return rows in random order and you need to remove `PERCENT` from the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 8 * FROM
(     
      SELECT TEXT, ID, Details 
      FROM tblTEXT 
      WHERE (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15)
)X  ORDER BY newid()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify what you want to get back from the result:
The * means that you want to see everythin.

```
select top (8) *
from 
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (
    select TEXT, ID, Details 
    from tblTEXT 
    where (ID = 12 or ID = 13 or ID =15) 

    ) X
    order by newid()
)
```

Comment: This does not return the rows in random order.